# jQuery .click() not working (debugging)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and am making a few `.click()` functions for my website, but no matter what I try, I can't get them to work.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#underlay-img-container-btns-add").click(function(){$("#underlay-img-container-form-file").click();});
    $("#underlay-img-container-btns-submit").click(function(){document.forms['underlay-img-container-form'].submit();$("#underlay-img-container-general_loader").css("display","inline-block");});
    $("#underlay-img-container-form-file").change(function(){readURLImg(this);});
    $("#underlay-gif-container-btns-add").click(function(){$("#underlay-gif-container-form-file").click();});
    $("#underlay-gif-container-btns-submit").click(function(){document.forms['underlay-gif-container-form'].submit();$("#underlay-gif-container-general_loader").css("display","inline-block");});
    $("#underlay-gif-container-form-file").change(function(){readURLImg(this);});
});
```

readURLImg (displays an image preview before submission. This is part of a file uploading script.):

```
function readURLImg(input){if(input.files&&input.files[0]){var reader=new FileReader();reader.onload=function(e){$("#underlay-img-container-preview").attr("style","background-image:url("+e.target.result+");color:#fafafa");}
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);}}
```

I am sure my ids are correct. I have been trying to find the answer for hours with no success.

Comment: Use your browser debugger to check if there are any errors.

Comment: Can you post the whole code ? Here you have bound click event listener to number of elements, did you trigger the events i.e did you try clicking those elements ?

Comment: There are no errors. Absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: @gvmani I tried clicking. Nothing happens. No errors. I will post more code.

Comment: Have you included the jquery js file?

Comment: line 2: file button can't be fired by js, you should change another way to do it.

Comment: What does `readURLImg(this);` do? Post it in th question.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @shmuli I do not think it is possible. To many external files, scripts, etc.

Comment: in lines 2,3 you have written $("#underlay-img-container-form-file").click(); , if you want the click handler to be executed use trigger() instead as            $("#underlay-img-container-form-file").trigger("click"); see https://api.jquery.com/trigger/    i suppose this is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have checked your website 
then I've clicked on button upload you picture > opened the terminal and test

```
$("#underlay-img-container-btns-add").click(function(){alert('btn clicked')})
```

and the results appears

So, your problem is to call the events when the popups are ready

[image]

to Understand the concept

close the popup and try the same code it will retrieve empty array '[]'

```
<div class="btn" id="green" >
    <div class="icon-image"></div>
    <span>Upload your picture</span>
</div>
```

and add

```
$('.btn#green').click(function() {
  $('.overlay').html($('.overlay').html().replace(/!non_select_tag!/g, 'img'));
  $('.overlay').html($('.overlay').html().replace(/!non_select_txt!/g, 'Picture'));

  // add you events

  $("#underlay-img-container-btns-add").click(function(){alert('btn clicked')})

  $('.overlay').show();


})
```

this will work

Comment: Could you post code that would fix the problem? It is probably not working because I am using one popup window for both buttons, just changing the tags.

Comment: I've edit the answer and it contains the solution for your problem

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("#underlay-img-container-btns-add").on( 'click', function () { ... });
```

may not work because content is dynamically created.

Comment: http://awkwardpetsiblings.com. That's the website. Upload button popup options do not work.

Comment: #Krii i do not see the id 'underlay-img-container-btns-add' in the html.

Comment: The element id is changed from `underlay-!non_select_tag!-container-btns-add` to ether `underlay-img-container-btns-add` or `underlay-gif-container-btns-add` depending on the button clicked. All `!non_select_tag!` and `!non_select_txt!` act as variables.

Comment: this script worked for me $('#underlay-img-container-btns-add').on('click', function(){ alert('123'); });

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#underlay-img-container-btns-add").bind( 'click', function () { ... });
```

Comment: I will try. The website takes a little bit to update external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To bind events to dynamically generated elements in DOM, you may use

```
    $('document').on( 'click', '#selector', function () { 
        ... 
    });
```

This binds event to the DOM rather than to the element directly, which may not exist all the time.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("body").delegate("#underlay-img-container-btns-add",'click',function(){
 ....
 });
```